# GLCanvas doesn't show up

Tags: gradle, opengl, jogl, worldwind

I am currently experiencing a very weird problem with Jogl. I will try my best to describe the problem.
My IDE is: IntelliJ Ultimate. Graphics Card: Intel HD Graphics 520.

Currently I am working with WorldWind. I have one "normal" Project that uses no Gradle, Maven etc. In that Project everything works normal and i see a Window opening. Then i have another Project that uses Gradle which has Jogl and Gluegen as a dependency like this:

`compile group: 'org.jogamp.gluegen', name: 'gluegen-rt-main', version: '2.3.2'`

`compile group: 'org.jogamp.jogl', name: 'jogl-all-main', version: '2.3.2'`

And when i want to create a `WorldWindGlCanvas` like this:
`WorldWindowGLCanvas wwd = new WorldWindowGLCanvas();`

nothing happens. I create the window using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` but the thread is just stuck at that point and i dont know why.

I dont really know if Gradle is the Problem but i also have received a project from a colleague that uses Gradle and it works on his computer but i have the same Problem as above. I also had a "normal" Jogl project where it just randomly stopped working from one day to another and now nothing shows up anymore so im quite certain that the problem has something to do with OpenGL.

I haven't found anything anywhere about this problem but maybe someone experienced something similar or has an idea what i can do.

Edit: I have the newest driver for my graphics card and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Rather ask your question on the official JogAmp forum. Please update your OpenGL driver. No, the problem isn't JOGL itself, we're not responsible for buggy drivers, we already do our best to work around some of their limitations, we can't do miracles. Therefore, you shouldn't be very certain that JOGL is to blame.

Comment: @gouessej Sorry i didn't mean Jogl itself I phrased that wrong :). The only thing I know for sure is that the program "freezes" when i create a WorldWindowGLCanvas. Thanks for your answer and sorry for the misunderstanding. I appreciate the work you guys are doing.